# Magento2: How to load category collection?

Tags: magento2, category, topmenu

I have to load the category collection and show it on top menu position on my Magento site. I have tried object manager concept but it's not correct method to follow so that I have to load it using dependency injection.

I have referred this http://www.blogtreat.com/how-to-get-category-collection-in-magento-2/, but I don't know where to use this and how to show it on frontend since I'm new in Magento.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Hi @Siva, At first you should try to create a custom module. It will help you.

Comment: Yes, i understand that I have to create custom module, my question is how to show that in top menu position?

Comment: Did you find the file for top position? Or can you please show me with screen shot where you want to put that categories?

Comment: @Mayur, I have managed to get the result. Now, I have to load sub category. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Shall I give in answer for subcategory?

Comment: @Mayur, Yes please

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom module with your PackageName and ModuleName

**1.Create a registration.php file at**

PackageName/ModuleName/registration.php

Add below code

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'PackageName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**2.Create a module.xml file at**

PackageName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

Add below code

```
<config xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="PackageName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**3.Create a CategoriesList.php file at**

PackageName\moduleName\Block\CategoriesList.php

Add below code

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\moduleName\Block;
class CategoriesList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false)
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');        

        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }


        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }


        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize); 
        }    

        return $collection;
    }


    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true);
    }
}
?>
```

**4.Create topmenu.phtml tempate  file at**

PackageName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml

Add below code

```
<ul class="your-class">
 <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>

    $categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(); 
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        //print_r($category->getData());
        echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
    }

    // get categories sorted by category 'name'
    $categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(true, false, 'name', false);
    foreach ($categories as $category) {    
        echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
    }

    // get current store's categories
    $categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {    
        echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
    }
</ul>
```

**5.Create default.xml layout file at (render your template at top menu postion )**

PackageName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name='catalog.topnav'>
                <action method='setTemplate'>
                        <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>PackageName_ModuleName::html/topmenu.phtml</argument>
                </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done that and got it works but how can I load sub category?

Comment: @Siva to load sub category refer answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290617/magento2-3-how-to-get-sub-category-for-parent-category/290678#290678

Comment: Please check answer to get any Level child category https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290898/how-to-get-sub-category-of-sub-category/290994#290994